# HTML anchor tag is not working after e.preventDefault()?

Tags: jquery, html

When I add `e.preventDefault();` in jQuery post method, dynamically generated anchor tag is not working.

**This is jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img-rounded').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {fname: this.id}
        );
    });
});
```

**This HTML code:**

```
<a href="<?php echo "viewProfile.php?id=" . $record['user_id'];?>" >
  <img class="img-rounded"  
  src=" <?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $record['user_photo1'] ?>"  
  id="<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>"alt="" width="70%" height="20%">
</a>
```

I want to know that what is the problem there.

**THIS IS LikeMail.php**

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo "";


    }
    else {

        include("db.php");
        $user1 = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    //    echo $user1;


        //This is being received from jquery

      $user2 = $_POST['fname'];

                //$lname = $_POST['surname'];


            //echo $lname;
            /*$sql = "UPDATE notification SET alert='$fname' WHERE id = '1'";
            if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
                echo "updated";*/


            $check_for_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
            $numrows_likes = mysqli_num_rows($check_for_likes);
            if (false == $numrows_likes) {
                echo mysqli_error($conn);
            }

            if ($numrows_likes >= 1) {
                echo '<input type="submit" value="Unlike" id="Unlike" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';


            }
        if ($numrows_likes == 0) {
                echo '<input type="submit" value="Like" id="Like" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';
            }


    }?>
    <div class="respond"></div>
```

[image: IMAGE OF ERROR]

**THIS IS test.js code where ajax function is calling**

```
function like()
{
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Like').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('GET','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

While user2.js is same as above jquery method

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` purpose is exactly what you are experiencing, it prevents the anchor from doing it's default behavior which is to jump to a location designated by `href`. When you say "working", what do you mean as an anchor or whatever your function is expected to do...because you weren't specific...work as in make it dance a jig? To do your taxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zain Farooq please make your question more specific i.e what you want to achieve? If e.preventDefault() is used then the default action of the event will not be triggered i.e, like in your case the anchor tag will not work.

EDIT1: If you want to send some data using post method on other page and then only anchor tag to work then you can use following code:

I have made some changes as:

```
<a class="profile" href="<?php echo "viewProfile.php?id=" . $record['user_id'];?>" >
  <img class="img-rounded"  
  src=" <?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $record['user_photo1'] ?>"  
  id="<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>"alt="" width="70%" height="20%">
</a>
```

And then Your JQuery code will looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $('.profile').on('click', function (e) {

                    //Get the href Link
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post("LikeMail.php",
                             {fname: $(this).find(".img-rounded").attr("id")}

                    ).done(function () {
                     //Redirecting to anchor destination.
                        window.location.href = href;

                    });
                });
            });
```

EDIT2: I don't get your question but if you want to check the response of post request you can use following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('.profile').on('click', function (e) {

                    //Get the href Link
                    var href = $(this).attr('href');

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.post("LikeMail.php",
                            {fname: $(this).find(".img-rounded").attr("id")}, function (returnedData) {

                        // Do whatever you want with returend data  
                        console.log(returnedData);

                    }).done(function () {

                        //Redirecting to anchor destination.
                        //window.location.href = href;


                    });

                });

            });
```

Comment: I have post method in jquery code. To make it send jquery post data to other page I had to add `e.preventDefault()` because content was inside anchor tag. But after adding `e.preventDefault()` jquery started send post data but anchor tag did not work. I want to fix both anchor tag and post method

Comment: Anchor tag is working but jquery is not sending data

Comment: I dont know why still it is not working. I have also used ajax call in other function to the same page (`LikeMail.php`) to which jquery post data is sending. can it be the problem?

Comment: I am sending jquery post data to `LikeMail.php` page and after ajax call to `LikeMail.php` from `viewProfile.php` page. This is complete scenario. is ajax call creating problem here?

Comment: You can inspect it with firebug that what response you are getting.

Comment: Nothing there... Blank

Comment: @ZainFarooq You can inspect with firebug. Your **LikeMail.php** has no error but i am not getting what you want to achieve. Sorry if I misinterpreted  your question.

Comment: I think you have got it. I want to make work both anchor tag and also jquery post method. Your code solution looks like tremendous but I dont know why it is not working. while there isn't any error in console

Comment: I have added you edited code.. It mentions line 12 in console but there is no error

Comment: Line 12 is ` (`console.log(returnedData);`)`

Comment: Also `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` from ajax call function

Comment: @ZainFarooq Can share error screenshots? It might help me to find what is going on. Your firebug post & response screenshots will be sufficient.

Comment: @ZainFarooq `req.open('GET','LikeMail.php','true');` uses GET method to post data while your `LikeMail.php` has POST method for handling AJAX request. You must use `$_REQUEST` method for handling both type of request. Also this error  is not  related to my code.

Comment: Ok.. I will take a look on it

Comment: Really sorry form disturbing you. I have checked it. jquery post is returning correct value in the page of anchor tag but it isn't returning anything in redirected page

Comment: Please give the relevent code that you want to implement. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have come closer to the solution but unfortunately couldn't reach the target. But thankyou very much

Answer (score 2):

`e.preventDefault()` is meant to prevent the default action from happening. In this case, it will not send you to the page you refer to, as that action will be cancelled.

You cannot make it send a POST request and transfer you at the same time, because the POST wouldn't send before the page starts loading the new page.

Instead you can send the POST and THEN change the page. You simply have to add

```
window.location = this.href;
```

after `$.post()` is done. This will change the location (the page you are on), to be the location specified in the a-tag. Simple :)

Because `this` will refer to the promise of `.done()`, you need to refer back to the `this` of the click function. Simply throw in a `$this` and set that to `this` of the click function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.img-rounded').on('click', function(e) {
         $this = this;
         e.preventDefault();
         $.post("LikeMail.php", {
             fname: this.id
         }).done(function() {
             window.location = $this.parentNode.href;
         });
     });
 });
```

EDIT: Thanks to Benjy for noticing this. You need to do `$this.parentNode.href`, as `this` is an image. You want to grab the parent element, which is the anchor tag.

Comment: $this.parentNode.href ($this is an image)

Comment: @Benjy It's always best practise to refer back to a variable instead of moving back using parents, children etc. If your HTML changes (or you Javascript for that matter), you would have to change the Javascript as well. EDIT: Oh, I see what you mean. I never saw the HTML. Derp.

Comment: Your logic is looking perfect but unfortunately page is still not redirecting

Comment: I have checked it in console it gives error `Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`

Comment: I'd use `$this.closest('a')` in case the image is then put inside a div/span for whatever reason.

Comment: @ZainFarooq `$this.closest('a').href`. Your anchor tag has no id, so it would be undefined. The HTML you posted above would work perfectly with the code I wrote. Unless you changed your HTML, my code should work. Either you're not including everything, or you are doing something wrong. You have to understand what you are doing, otherwise you're just doing stuff for no reason. `.href` grabs the value of the href attribute on the element. `window.location` changes the page to a new page. You obviously want to change the location to the `href`.

Comment: Actually I have found exact problem that my jquery post data lost on redirected page